# How to place one Display Object relative to another Display Object dynamically?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to place an image in another DisplayObject ( Vector Object ) when the reference object can vary in size and position.

```
local memoRect = display.newRect(135,100,440,540)
local memoTitle = display.newImage("images/memobg.png", 135, 100)
```

I want to place `memoTitle` *inside* the bounds of `memoRect` in a relative way. But the following code doesn't work.

```
local memoRect = display.newRect(135,100,440,540)
local memoTitle = display.newImage("images/memobg.png", memoRect.x + 10, memoRect.y + 20)
```

I would expect the above code to place `memoTitle` at the upper left of `memoRect` instead this code places `memoTitle` origin at the `X` center of `memoRect` and the `Y` top/0.

Is this the expected behavior?
Is this a bug?

How do I place `DisplayObjects` relative to one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *correct* answer that I derived after a couple hours of trying different things is basically the `referencePoint` default is absurdly set to `display.CenterReferencePoint` instead of `display.TopLeftReferencePoint`

Once I did the following everything behaved as I expected.

```
local memoRect = display.newRect(0,0,440,540)
local memoTitle = display.newImage("images/memobg.png", 0, 0)
memoRect:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
memoTitle:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
memoRect.x = 135; memoRect.y = 100
memoTitle.x = memoRect.x + 10; memoTitle.y = memoRect.y + 20
```

everything is now working relative to each other ( actually the DisplayGroup that they are in ). This way I can move one thing and the other things will position themselves relative to that object.

*I don't know the absurd logic behind making the default `display.CenterReferencePoint` but it isn't logical at all my any reasoning I can imagine.*

Comment: The default is center center, not top center.